# laravel oneToMany query return all records by taggable_id and taggable_type

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

i want to select all `user_tag_id` where they have the same `taggable_type` and `taggable_id`. FYI, im not that good at using query and laravel is still new to me so im still learning.

this is what i've tried so far,

```
$check = Tag::whereIn('user_tag_id', function ( $query ) {
            $query->select('taggable_id')->from('tags')->groupBy('user_tag_id');
        })->get();
        return $check;
```

which did return this,

```
"id" => 1
        "user_tag_id" => 1
        "taggable_type" => "App\Domains\TradeSetup\Models\TradeSetup"
        "taggable_id" => 1
        "type" => null
        "state" => null
        "created_at" => "2022-11-25 01:57:42"
        "updated_at" => "2022-11-25 01:57:42"
        "deleted_at" => null

"id" => 6
        "user_tag_id" => 1
        "taggable_type" => "App\Domains\Trade\Models\Trade"
        "taggable_id" => 1
        "type" => null
        "state" => null
        "created_at" => "2022-11-25 02:31:24"
        "updated_at" => "2022-11-25 02:31:24"
        "deleted_at" => null
```

this is the model:

```
//TradeSetup model

    public function userTag()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserTag::class);
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
    }

// Tag model

public function taggable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function userTag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserTag::class);
    }
```

except i don't know how to only return, for example user_tag_id where taggable_type = TradeSetup and taggable_id = 1

basically i suspect the query would look something like this

```
SELECT USER_TAG_ID
FROM TAGS
WHERE (TAGGABLE_ID = 1) AND
WHERE (TAGGABLE_TYPE = TRADESETUP)
```

so i suspect the it will only return all the records based on user_tag_id which have taggable_id = 1 and taggable_type = TradeSetup.

Comment: Do you just want to get `user_tag_id`s where `taggable_type = TradeSetup` and `taggable_id = 1`? If not please explain it more clearly.

Comment: i'm sorry let me edit the question quickly @VüsalHüseynli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly you have a user relation for the tags model. So the query should look like this

```
Tag::whereHas('user_tag_id', function ($query) {
   $query->where('taggable_id', 1)->where('taggable_type', 'App\Domains\TradeSetup\Models\TradeSetup');
})->get();
```

If I misunderstood your model setup lemme know in the comments so I can edit the answer, Cheers!

EDIT 1#
So as I understand you, you only need to return tags where they have the UserTag relationship so you can do that like this

```
Tag::whereHas('userTag')->where('taggable_id', 1)->where('taggable_type', 'App\Domains\TradeSetup\Models\TradeSetup')->get()
```

Comment: Eloquent's `whereHas` method is to check existence of relation. You should define relation name as first parameter like: `Tag::whereHas('user', function()){}...`. Not the field name

Comment: Of course, but he has not specified what the name of the relation is!

Comment: You are right but I believe that it definitely can not be `user_tag_id` :)

Comment: I agree with you 100% :)

Comment: @dz0nika i made some edits. im sorry as im trying hard to explain it best as i could. i hope you bear with me and understand what i want

Comment: @dz0nika Thank You. you saved my life. this definitely helps me alot